# Issue in binding of nested object in angular

Tags: angular

In angular 6 while I am binding a nested model to view, its giving error as "Can't read property of undefined".

Model-

```
    export class Country {
    CountryID: number;
    CountryCode: string;
    CountryName: string;
    CurrencyCode: string;
}

export class Data {
    Country: Country[]
}

export class CountryMaster {
    IsSuccess: boolean;
    ErrorCode: string;
    ErrorDescription: string;
    Data: Data;
}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CountryMaster, Country,Data } from '../Shared/Model/CountryModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping',
  templateUrl: './shopping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public httpCl: HttpClient) { }
  ListOfCountry: Data;
  countries: Country[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.BindCountry();
  }

  BindCountry(): void {


  this.httpCl.get("http://localhost:59049/api/Country/GetCountry").subscribe(
      (successData: CountryMaster) => {
        this.ListOfCountry = successData.Data;
      },failData => {
        //alert(failData);        
      });
  }
}
```

and template

```
  <div *ngFor="let ctry of ListOfCountry.Country">
  <div>
    <label>{{ctry.CountryCode}}</label>
    <label>{{ctry.CountryName}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though it bind the data but also give the error in console. When i pass the list of Country model to view then it works fine or when i added a condition `*ngIf="ListOfCountry"` then there is no error. Can anyone help me why its happening when I am binding with nested object

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen in cases where your data response is received after the view has been rendered.

Though the API has been called in ngOnInit() but depending upon your API response time, data may arrive after view rendering.

In that case, the `ListOfCountry: Data;` doesn't have the definition for the Data object type. It is just declared, not defined. Thus, it isn't able to find the `Country` object in it.

You may declare your object as below to ignore this condition:

```
ListOfCountry: Data = { Country = [] };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by using a safe navigation operator  ?

```
div *ngFor="let ctry of ListOfCountry?.Country">
  <div>
    <label>{{ctry?.CountryCode}}</label>
    <label>{{ctry?.CountryName}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its same as adding <div *ngIf="ListOfCountry"> before binding, which will solve the issue but main concern is why it's happening.